# BebasNeueCyrillic прилипает к верхнему краю в linux manjaro, как исправить?

Tags: css, linux, шрифты, manjaro

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я сижу на linux manjaro и заметил, что есть ряд шрифтов, которые отображаются некорректно, показал на скрине. Прилипает к верхнему краю. На винде все ок. Уже второй день бьюсь, может кто подскажет в какую сторону надо копать?